# Likelihood of consecutive ids in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm currently developing a node app using mongodb. I'm currently looking up the value of an item, if it exists, deleting it, if not, then writing the value (basically a toggle).

The last 4 times I just did this, I got the following auto generated _ids:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("567f566206eedcc838ce86a0")
"_id" : ObjectId("567f566206eedcc838ce86a1")
"_id" : ObjectId("567f566206eedcc838ce86a2")
"_id" : ObjectId("567f566206eedcc838ce86a3")
```

I'm currently using Windows if that makes a difference. From what I understand of mongo ids, these ids should be generated in a fairly random manner, so how was I able to get 3 sequential ids? (I'm not altering the ids in anyway).

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB ids are not in fact random and follow a very strict rule:

"
ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:

a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
a 3-byte machine identifier,
a 2-byte process id, and
a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value."

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/

While the last value is random, assuming that you did this generation at nearly the same time, it's not terribly unlikely.

Comment: The 4 byte value alone should nullify the likelihood of these sequential ids since these actions are taking place sometimes minutes apart (it's still reproducible for me). Thank you however for the reference.